# How do I redirect printf to new Konsole window in C?

Tags: c, linux, konsole

I have program, which uses threads to run 2 functions separately. I want output of func1 be in console window from which I launch program and output of func2 to be in newly created window. Any suggested solutions on that?

I use system("konsole"); to create new console in func2, but it just freezes output in first window (I mean program is running, but output is frozen till I close new console window).

Comment: The `system` function is *blocking*. It will not return until the command you run finish. Considering you want to specifically use Konsole, I assume you're on a KDE system? I'm sure that the KDE framework have some way to open a console window and give you a way to output to it.

Comment: Is there a way to start `konsole` with a program running? If you can (in a non-blocking way, not `system()`) create console with a program you control, that program can relay output. You may be able to communicate either over the network or maybe via a file or a unix socket.

Comment: You probably what to look into `popen()`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (on Linux with `/proc` mounted by default; other operating systems, or Linux with /proc not mounted, won't work).

```
  #define KONSOLE_BUFSIZE 512
  char buf[KONSOLE_BUFSIZE];
  FILE* p = popen("konsole -e 'sh -c \"cat /proc/$PPID/fd/0\"'", "w");
  if (p == NULL ) { /* process error */ }
  setvbuf(p, buf, _IOLBF, KONSOLE_BUFSIZE);

  ...

  pclose(p);
```

Writes to `p` appear in the konsole window. We rely on the fact that the parent process of the shell is the terminal emulator itself, and steal its standard input.

A more POSIX-y way would be to set up a named pipe and have the program write to it, while `cat` in a spawned terminal emulator is reading from it.

Answer (score 0):

Small simplifications to n. m. could be an AI's fine answer:

```
    FILE *p = popen("konsole -e cat /proc/$$/fd/0", "w");
    …
    setlinebuf(p);
```

Besides, it may be worth noting that `pclose` causes `cat` and therewith `konsole` to terminate; if one rather wants to wait for the console window to be closed, `wait(NULL)` can be used before provided that no other child has been spawned.